# User Defined Function MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I execute a user defined function so that the database will recognize that the function has been created?

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION `StudentGPA` (StudentID int, ClassStartDateStart datetime, ClassStartDateEnd date time) RETURNS  decimal(3,2) 
BEGIN 

Declare AvgGPA decimal(3,2); 

SELECT AvgGPA= isNULL(Avg(GPA), 0.0) 
FROM Students_Classes 
WHERE StudentID = StudentID 
  AND StartDate > ClassStartDateStart 
  AND StartDate <= ClassStartDateEnd 
  AND GPA > 0; RETURN AvgGPA; 

END
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Also you should add a delimiter to your `END` statement like this `END$$` and then change the delimiter back afterwards using `DELIMITER ;`

Comment: There are no errors with the code itself, as far as the program can tell. Where would I change the delimiter in the code, after or before the END?

Comment: When I tell it to Execute Statement from the Query tab, it doesn't do anything.

Comment: "doesn't do anything" is not normal behaviour, workbench should always give you a result at the bottom in the Output section. If this isn't visible go to **View > Output** to turn it on. You can also check the **routines** section of your database in the Object Browser to see if the function appears there.

Answer (score 0):

When running your code, you should get a syntax error. In your `CREATE` statement where you're specifying your parameters you need to change `ClassStartDateEnd date time` to `ClassStartDateEnd datetime`.

```
DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE FUNCTION `StudentGPA` 
  (StudentID int, 
   ClassStartDateStart datetime, 
   ClassStartDateEnd datetime)
  RETURNS decimal(3,2) 

BEGIN 

  Declare AvgGPA decimal(3,2); 

  SELECT AvgGPA= isNULL(Avg(GPA), 0.0) 
  FROM Students_Classes 
  WHERE StudentID = StudentID 
    AND StartDate > ClassStartDateStart 
    AND StartDate <= ClassStartDateEnd 
    AND GPA > 0; RETURN AvgGPA; 

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have also used your DELIMITER of `$$` after your `END` statement to properly terminate the `CREATE`, then set the delimiter back to `;` which is good practice.

Comment: it now comes back and says that it is not allowed to return a result set. Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you change it to something like `AvgGPA = (SELECT ....)` that should avoid the error.